# Refreshing tableView flashes when reloading data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, refresh, indexoutofrangeexception

So a refresh function kept crashing my app because of an index out of range issue. I then added the reloadData after first emptying my list. Now I get this flicker when refreshing because it first loads the empty list then the filled list. Where should I empty the list or how can I get rid of the flickering? Im using swift 3 and Xcode 8.2.1

```
func getData()
{
    fetchedUsers.removeAll()
    self.userTableView.reloadData()

    //myphpfileurl
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error")
        }
        else{
            do{
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSArray

                for eachFetchedUsers in fetchedData {
                    let eachUsers = eachFetchedUsers as! [String : Any]
                    let id = eachUsers["id"] as! String
                    let name = eachUsers["Nimi"] as! String
                    let email = eachUsers["Sahkoposti"] as! String
                    let company = eachUsers["Yritys"] as! String

                    self.fetchedUsers.append(Users(id : id, name: name, email : email, company: company))

                }
                self.userTableView.reloadData()
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }
            catch{
                print("Error 2")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: `self.userTableView.reloadData()
self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()`

you need to call there on MainThread

`DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.userTableView.reloadData()
      self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this For reload the table

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.userTableView.reloadData() 
      self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
  }
```

Comment: I tried to add this but the cells still keep flickering as they go empty first. And if i remove the self.userTableView.reloadData() on line 4 the app crashes when i refresh many times.

Comment: @SimoKorpikoski call Rest API in synchronus mode.make one function do the code for rest api and call this function from viewdidload